# How Use get method to do different functions PHP .?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I wrote a simple php file to open different websites using different URLs. 
PHP code is here.(it's file name is user.php)

```
<?php 

$id =  $_GET["name"] ;

 if ($id=joe) {

header('Location: http://1.com');
}

 if ($id=marry) {

header('Location: http://2.com');
}

 if ($id=katty) {

header('Location: http://3.com');
}

?>
```

I used those 3 methods to call php file.

```
1.http://xxxxxx.com/user.php?name=joe
2.http://xxxxxx.com/user.php?name=marry
3.http://xxxxxx.com/user.php?name=katty
```

But php file opens only http://3.com at every time.How to fix this.?
how to open different websites for each names.?

Comment: Your operators are missing the comparison `if ($id=='katty')` and wrapping the compared value in single or double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison is wrong.  joe, marry and katty are string type

```
<?php 

$id =  $_GET["name"] ;

 if ($id=='joe') { //<--- here

header('Location: http://1.com');
}

 if ($id=='marry') { //<--- here

header('Location: http://2.com');
}

 if ($id=='katty') { //<--- here

header('Location: http://3.com');
}

?>
```

Here is PHP comparison operator description.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @FredGandt, Thank you for your guide.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `==` for conditional statements not `=`

```
 if you use = , you say :
 $id='joe'; 
 $id='marry';
 $id='katty';

 if($id='katty') return 1 boolean
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, using the `==` vs `=` is what's wrong with what you have, however whenever you are doing a script take care to not be redundant. You may also want to think about making a default setting should no conditions be met:

```
<?php
# Have your values stored in a list, makes if/else unnecessary
$array = array(
    'joe'=>1,
    'marry'=>2,
    'katty'=>3,
    'default'=>1
);
# Make sure to check that something is set first
$id    = (!empty($_GET['name']))? trim($_GET['name']) : 'default';
# Set the domain
$redirect = (isset($array[$id]))? $array[$id] : $array['default'];
# Rediret
header("Location: http://{$redirect}.com");
# Stop the execution
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like your question has been answered above but it's probably not that clear for you, if you're just beginning (using arrays, short php if statements etc).

I'm assuming that you're just learning PHP considering what you're trying to achieve, so here is a simplified answer that is easier to understand than what some other people have posted here:

```
<?php
    // Check that you actually have a 'name' being submitted that you can assign
    if (!empty($_GET['name'])) {
        $id = $_GET['name'];
    }
    // If there isn't a 'name' being submitted, handle that
    else {
        // return an error or don't redirect at all
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }

    // Else your code will keep running if an $id is set
    if ($id == 'joe') {
        header('Location: http://1.com');
    }

    if ($id=marry) {
        header('Location: http://2.com');
    }

    if ($id=katty) {
        header('Location: http://3.com');
    }
?>
```

Hope this helps you better understand what's happening.